# Google Chart API - always have to create new Date() objects for dates?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

In my app, I am returning some values from a SQL instance through Python (via AJAX call) in the following format:

```
[['2012-11-18', 33, 2], ['2012-11-19', 162, 11], ['2012-11-20', 140, 13]]
```

Unfortunately, if I want Google Chart API to recognize this as dates rather than strings, I seem to need to use `new Date(x)` object creation in Javascript. Is this always necessary? How could I achieve this from my current output programmatically, either in Javascript or Python? Any hints would be helpful!

Below doesn't work

```
...
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Pageviews');
data.addColumn('number', 'Unique Visitors');
data.addRows([['2012-11-18', 33, 2], ['2012-11-19', 162, 11], ['2012-11-20', 140, 13]]); 
...
```

Below works:

```
...
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'Pageviews');
data.addColumn('number', 'Unique Visitors');
data.addRows([[new Date('2012-11-18'), 33, 2], [new Date('2012-11-19'), 162, 11], [new Date('2012-11-20'), 140, 13]]); 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dateArray = [['2012-11-18', 33, 2], ['2012-11-19', 162, 11], ['2012-11-20', 140, 13]];
for(var i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i++){
    dateArray[i][0] = new Date(dateArray[i][0]); // Set dateArray[i][0] to a `new Date()` with as value the string in `dateArray[i][0]`;
}
data.addRows(dateArray);
```

This will set the date strings to date objects, in the array.